# About Android Firebase retrieve data(No setter/field error)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just want to retrieve data from my `firebase` database, but I don't know the correct way to get that data. Here is my error in android studio:

```
  W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for chapterTwo found on class 
  com.junburg.moon.rockbottom.model.Chapter
  W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for chatperOne found on class 
  com.junburg.moon.rockbottom.model.Chapter
  W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for chapterTwo found on class 
  com.junburg.moon.rockbottom.model.Chapter
  W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for chapterOne found on class 
  com.junburg.moon.rockbottom.model.Chapter
```

And here is my data classes. This is a `Chapter.class` model.

```
public class Chapter {

    private String chaterName;
    private String chaterExplain;

    public Chapter() {
    }

    public Chapter(String chaterName, String chaterExplain) {
        this.chaterName = chaterName;
        this.chaterExplain = chaterExplain;
    }

    public String getChaterName() {
        return chaterName;
    }

    public void setChaterName(String chaterName) {
        this.chaterName = chaterName;
    }

    public String getChaterExplain() {
        return chaterExplain;
    }

    public void setChaterExplain(String chaterExplain) {
        this.chaterExplain = chaterExplain;
    }
}
```

And the `Study.class` model

```
public class Subject {
  private String subjectName;
  private String subjectExplain;
  private Chapter chapter;

  public Subject() {
  }

  public Subject(String subjectName, String subjectExplain, Chapter 
   chapter) {
    this.subjectName = subjectName;
    this.subjectExplain = subjectExplain;
    this.chapter = chapter;
  }

   public String getSubjectName() {
      return subjectName;
   }

   public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
   }

   public String getSubjectExplain() {
       return subjectExplain;
   }

    public void setSubjectExplain(String subjectExplain) {
       this.subjectExplain = subjectExplain;
   }

    public Chapter getChapter() {
       return chapter;
   }

   public void setChapter(Chapter chapter) {
        this.chapter = chapter;
   }
}
```

And this is my `addValueEventListener` code:

```
 private void getStudyData() {
      databaseReference.child("study")
     .child("subject")
     .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        subjectList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Subject subject = ds.getValue(Subject.class);
            subjectList.add(subject);
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + 
      subject.getChapter().getChaterName()  + 
      subject.getChapter().getChaterExplain());

        }
        studyRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Finally, This is my JSON Tree in Firebase database.

[image]

I tried some methods, but I could not solve this error.

The code execution does not return the Chapter class data. For example:

```
subject.getChapter().getChaterName() 
subject.getChapter().getChaterExplain()
```

I would appreciate your help handling this one. And Thank you for caring.

Comment: Well formatted 1st question (+1). welcome to SO mate!

Comment: Where is your JSON?

Comment: @ReazMurshed Oh my god. I don't know why photo was not attatched.. Now Image is existing!

Comment: @RannLifshitz Thank you! Someone convert my pour english question. Really awesome! SO!

Comment: @Junburg, you can see the edited history if you want to see who has edited your question. Anyway, please check the answer below and let me know if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Wow! You edit it! You genius! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your POJO class of `Chapter`. First, the error message is clearly saying that the `chapterOne` and `chapterTwo` attributes are missing. You need that in your POJO.

So your `Chapter.java` should look like this.

```
public class Chapter {
    public ChapterOne chapterOne;
    public ChapterTwo chapterTwo;
}
```

And the `ChapterOne` and `ChapterTwo` classes are needed to be defined as well.

```
public class ChapterOne extends ChapterDetails {

}

public class ChapterTwo extends ChapterDetails {

}

public class ChapterDetails {
    public String chapterName;
    public String chapterExplain;
}
```

Note that you have misspelled the `chapterName` and the `chapterExplain` in your `Chapter` pojo that you have. The current variable names are `chaterName` and `chaterExplain` which is wrong. Please fix the variable names as well.

**Update**

> But can i get data to change variable type in chapter data of subject
>   class? List.. Map.. or.. somethnig else like that. Not make new class
>   ChapterOne.. ChapterTwo..

With your current implementation this is not possible. However, I would suggest a slight change in your firebase database implementation. Let us take the `chapter` node for the modification.

```
chapter
    - chapterDetails
        - chapterId : 1
        - chapterName : Something one
        - chapterExplain : Some explanation
    - chapterDetails
        - chapterId : 2
        - chapterName : Something two
        - chapterExplain : Some explanation
```

If you modify your firebase database structure like the above, then you might come up wit the following POJO class.

```
public class Chapter {
    List<ChapterDetails> chapterDetails;
}

public class ChapterDetails {
    public Long chapterId;
    public String chapterName;
    public String chapterExplain;
}
```

> I'm sorry I asked too much. But the same chapterDetail is not added to
>   the Firebases. I tried to add a chapterDetail with chapterId 1 and a
>   chapterDetail with chapterId 2, but it disappears or is replaced.

I just shown a pseudo implementation. Sorry if the updated answer was misleading. However, please set your data in firebase database using the following. So that you can get your data as a list from firebase.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/chapter"):
List<Chapter> chapterList = new ArrayList<Chapter>();
// Now populate your chapterList with the chapters 
addItemsInYourChapterList();
ref.setValue(chapterList);
```

Now while retrieving the data from firebase database like the following.

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          System.out.println("There are " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " chapters");
          for (DataSnapshot chapterSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Chapter chapter = chapterSnapshot.getValue(Chapter.class);
            // Get your chapter details here.
          }
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
          System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
      }
  });
```

Please note that I am taking the `chapter` node into consideration only. Modify the code as per your need.

Comment: OMG. misspelled.. But can i get data to change variable type in chapter data of subject class? List.. Map.. or.. somethnig else like that. Not make new class ChapterOne.. ChapterTwo..

Comment: I'm sorry I asked too much. But the same chapterDetail is not added to the Firebases. I tried to add a chapterDetail with chapterId 1 and a chapterDetail with chapterId 2, but it disappears or is replaced.

Comment: Don't worry. I am really glad to help. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Really Thank you for your answer. It will be good example and help!

Answer (score 1):

To read data from the database, you need an instance of DatabaseReference:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Then you can add a user with setValue() as follows:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
```

See example here retrieving the details of a post from the database:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
}
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```